# Naming pages for dynamic routing in NextJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-redux, next.js

How can I achieve this link `'/employees/10/edit'` in the pages directory?

I have tried the following where [id] is a directory.

```
/employees/[id]/edit.js
```

Comment: did you write your own custom routing for this?

Comment: no, I am new to it.

Comment: In Next.js you can add brackets to a page ([param]) to create a dynamic route (a.k.a. url slugs, pretty urls...)

e.g.

```import { useRouter } from 'next/router'

const Post = () => {
  const router = useRouter()
  const { pid } = router.query

  return <p>Post: {pid}</p>
}

export default Post
```

More information on Dynamic Routing [here](https://nextjs.org/docs#dynamic-routing)

Answer (score 4):

Try this :

```
pages
 -employees (directory)
   --[id] (directory)
     ---edit.js (file)
```

[image: Edit competent-chaplygin-je2jr]